# Prerequisites for Ptolemy's Almagest

Tags: astronomy, soft-question, education, history, celestial-mechanics

I hope this is a valid question to ask on this website (since it's astronomy and not e.g. mechanics, I wasn't so sure).

What prerequisites are needed for fully understanding [Ptolemy's Almagest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almagest). Fully understanding means being able to understand what I read *without getting stuck anywhere due to a lack of knowledge*.)

Comment: You need to learn Latin (unless you have an English translation). Another requisite: a lot of spare time.

Comment: @julianfernandez: I have G.J.Toomer's English version -- and don't worry about spare time. ;-)

Comment: well, euclidean geometry (preferably from the *Elements*) would be needed, plus some familiarity with the Babylonian approximations (and fractions) plus understanding of Latin or Anc. Greek or translation

Comment: @NikosM.: Why was I told that people used to read a collection of works entitled "The Little Astronomy" (which includes e.g. Euclid's Phaenomena) as a stepping stone to Ptolemy? It seems there are solid prerequisites needed. Plus the knowledge that Ptolemy assumes you know about Calenders, Egyptian astronomy, etc.

Comment: @user45220, sure there are pre-requisites. And if one wants to fully merge into the text would have to have a good familiarity with the phiolosophical schools of thought which shaped the Hellenistic period (Pythagoreans, Plato, Aristotle). Just Aristotle is a huge work. Then Euclid of course, Appolonius and conic sections, a familiarity with Babylonian mathematics (since babylonian approximations are used in Almagest). Some theorems of Pappus as well. i guess this would make a fairly good background

Answer (score 2):

Richard Fitzpatrick's free e-book [***A Modern Almagest: An Updated Version of Ptolemy’s Model of the Solar System***](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Syntaxis/Almagest.pdf) presents a modernized version of [Ptolemy's *Almagest*](https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/10122240).

(I mention it [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133845/10024).)

Answer (score -1):

I have Toomer’s translation and I have translated the *Almagest* to French myself, and other than, as mentioned, Euclidean geometry, I had no previous knowledge that was needed for understanding it.